# correct tense of meet [we meet now] or [we have met now]

Tags: tense

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) I have not come across any interesting people until we **meet** now.

(2) I have not come across any interesting people until we **have met** now.

Which tense of "meet" is correct? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately both sentences are unnatural, and it is hard to know what you mean.  You should probably completely rephrase to something like "you're the first interesting person that I've met."   I've voted to close because "which one is correct" is unanswerable. Both are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collins Dictionary defines *until*:

> 1. PREPOSITION A1

> If something happens *until* a particular time, it happens during the period *before* that time and *stops* at that time [emphasis added].

Though the meeting has just happened, it is past.  Hence we use *met*.

> I *didn’t* come across any interesting people until we *met*.

> I *hadn’t* come across any interesting people until we *met*.

Both the simple past *didn’t* and the past perfect *hadn’t* are possible as the sequence of events is obvious.